# python - split list into unique sub-lists, each with sum of members in given range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of *N* decimal numbers (floats), and I need to split it into sub-lists (of any length) -- where each sub-list's sum is in a given range; let's say -- between *X* and *Y*. (both positive and sequential, and *Y* is not larger than 100)

**The list can have members of the same value, but a list member can't appear in more than one sub-lists.**

Some details regarding the list:

- All list members are positive, and are in the X-Y range.
- There are not more than 50 members.

Given the list's small size, the algorithm's efficiency isn't really critical.

An example of a "valid" list for  (as requested in a comment below):

```py
data = [9.99, 12.50, 13.49, 9.99, 11.99, 16.34, 39.99, 24.99, 32.99, 25.99, 14.99]
```

How would you achieve in python?

Comment: depending on the range of sums you accept and the given input, this may be a hard problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem it might be helpful to add more details (are your numbers positive? what is the range of the sums? etc...)

Comment: Are all individual numbers in the given range themselves?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist , PM - No problem, I've updated the question with the data you requested. Thanks!

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, they are

Comment: Seems to be a job for [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).